# Is it possible for the paper to be accepted in this case?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission

I am a computer professional. I submitted a paper to the top conference in our field.  I just received comments from reviewers. Now is the rebuttal stage.

There are six reviewers in total. `2 Accecpt, 2 weak accecpt, one weak reject and one reject`.

The reviewer who gave the reject comment obviously had a problem with the conceptual understanding of the paper. The remaining reviewers think the idea of the paper is interesting, but the evaluation is not good.

How should I reply? Is there any chance for this paper?

Comment: What does 'voted...top meeting' mean?  Whether a paper is accepted depends on the 'cut-off' or the number of papers that a chair wants to have in a conference.  For example, he/she may need some number of papers to break even.  You may have more useful feedback if you name the conference you submitted your paper to.

Comment: Thank you! I just corrected it.

Comment: Based on the scores alone, yes, there might be a chance. But it depends on the nature of the feedback and on the strength of support for the paper (for example, if the positive reviewers are experts). That is impossible for us to answer without knowing all details.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't receive a "reject" decision, it's possible for your paper to be accepted.*

You reply the same way you do with any revise decision - make the changes you think are an improvement, rebut the suggestions you think do not help, and [clarify whatever it was that caused the last reviewer to have the "conceptual problem"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5865/what-to-do-if-reviewers-reject-a-paper-without-understanding-the-content/5933#5933).

*Technically it's possible for even a rejected paper to be subsequently accepted, if you appeal the decision.

Comment: I think that this answer doesn't apply to the question: during the rebuttal stage in CS conferences, one doesn't revise the paper. The rebuttal phase is also not a "revise" decision.